# Gradle publishToMavenLocal

Tags: jenkins, gradle, build.gradle

When I use gradle clean build publishToMavenLocal with

```
publishing {
    publications {
        maven(MavenPublication) {
            from components.java
        }
    }
}
```

using gradle 7.1.
It works on local gradle build. However, when I run on Jenkins, I get:

```
org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.steps.MissingContextVariableException: Required context class hudson.FilePath is missing
Perhaps you forgot to surround the code with a step that provides this, such as: node
```

When, I comment out the publishing section in build.gradle it works in Jenkins.

Any ideas?

Thanks

Comment: Please provide the Jenkins pipeline, which the error message is referring to.

Answer (score 1):

Publishing to Maven local requires disk space, or working space.

Based on: https://support.cloudbees.com/hc/en-us/articles/4402585187483-How-to-troubleshoot-hudson-FilePath-is-missing-in-a-Pipeline-run

Comment: It is working now with publishing section. It may have been a  space issue or some other Jenkins issue.